# How to get selected node from WebView in JavaFX2

Tags: webview, javafx-2

I can get the selected text by next code snippet:
String selection = (String) webView.getEngine().executeScript("window.getSelection().toString()");
System.out.println(selection);

But is there anyway to get the selected node for I want to add content into the dom tree.

Answer (score 1):

this is more of a javascript question, because executeScript solely executes javascript and retuns whatever the script returns. I'd try

```
document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode
```

this returns the parent node of the container that yields the selected parts.